# Ошибка при сохранении таблицы

Tags: qt, xls

```
def save_file(self):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Myfile.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for x in range(self.table.rowCount()):
        data = []
        for y in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            item_data = self.table.item(x, y)
            if item_data is not None:
                data.append(item_data)
        worksheet.insert_image('A1', data)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not list

Comment: 1) Какая строка кода вызвала ошибку? 2) Какое слово в сообщении об ошибке не удалось перевести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `insert_image` имеет следующий вид:

```
insert_image(row, col, image[, options])
```

А Вы вместо строки с названием картинки (`image`) передаёте список `data`, что и вызывает ошибку. Для исправления Вам необходимо указать, какой именно элемент из этого списка использовать, т.е. что-то вроде этого:

```
worksheet.insert_image('A1', data[0])
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема глубже оказалась

Comment: Теперь дает вот такую ошибку IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Dr.robot ну а в чём вопрос? Вы указываете индекс, выходящий за пределы массива, поэтому и получаете такую ошибку.